# creating user profiles, each with personal mysql data, using php

Tags: mysql, database, relational

I'm trying to figure out the best practices for storing user data on a php/mysql site.
let's say the website will host a service of saving people's input for items they have in their house.
I have set up tables that includes: kitchen, bathroom, bedroom, etc.
Sally adds her 6 kitchen items.
John adds his 3 kitchen items.
etc.

I'm just wondering what may be the common practice on storing other user information in the mysql database. I've taken a class on databases, so i'm thinking relationally linking by foreign key, john with his items in the lists, and sally too..

does that sound about right? or is there a better way? I can see the list getting really large quite quickly.

would it be possible to set up a different table to each user? is that possible? or would it be silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not set up a table for each user.

Definitely go relational. I am not sure I follow you completely around "john with his items.." and so on. So I interpret this as

```
user table
room table
item table
relational user->item (id, user_id, item_id, room_id) OR:
relational item->room
```

So you can pull a user, list the rooms they have related to them, then list the items in that room. Additionally, like this you do not need a new item entry for common things like tables, stoves, spatulas, etc.

Your list could get large, but if you scale properly and plan a back end based update migration when you absolutely need to (like millions of users) then you should be fine. Consider how many relations sites like facebook and ebay have to maintain. Large relations are normal for databases so I wouldn't let a couple million rows scare you.

Comment: i like your answer, very thorough, i think i got it! .. for the time being.. until i run into something else, 5 mins later.. :)

Comment: int unsigned goes up to 4,294,967,295 ... you expect to have over 4.29 billion users? here's the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html - Keep in mind, should you grow that large you can always migrate to a stronger db, better structure, etc. Plan for what you can reasonably project. Otherwise you may waste tons of time over engineering something that could have easily been done in a fraction of the time and effort.

Comment: yea, good point, i kinda erased the comment, as i figured it out, but i appreciate your, once again thorough answer. i tend to over engineer at the moment, because i am a beginner and just learning the tools of the trade. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use three tables:

- `rooms (id, room)`, to store values `kitchen, bathroom, bedroom`, etc.
- `users`
- `items`: assuming you have a common structure your your current kitchen, bathroom, bedroom tables, one table could replace all of them. This table should also contain two foreign keys, `user_id` and `room_id`.

With that structure, you can easily retrieve and filter your data.